# Scipy curve_fit is not optimizing one of three parameters

Tags: optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit use scipy curve_fit to fit my experimental data. The objective function has been derived in a way that the first two parameters are significant for my study. I have added in a third parameter since my curve needs to be shifts. For some reason, scipy is not changing that parameter at all. After playing around I know that I want this third (K_shift) parameter to be around 300.

```
def objective_function(x,k_in,k_out,k_shift):
    k_shift = int(k_shift)
    aifVec[:k_shift] = 0
    C = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        part = np.trapz(aifVec[0:i]* np.exp(-k_out * (timeTumor[i] - timeTumor[0:i])))
        C.append(k_in * part)
    C = np.array(C)
    return C

# optimizing k_in and k_out and k_shift
inital_guess = np.asarray([0.01,0.01,300.0])
fit = curve_fit(objective_function,timeTumor,tumorVec, p0=inital_guess)
ans, cov = fit
fit_tumorY = objective_function(timeTumor, ans[0],ans[1],ans[2])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(tumor_x , tumor_y, 'o', timeTumor, fit_tumorY, '-')
plt.legend(['tumor', 'fit'], loc='best')
rSqTumor = r2_score(tumorVec,fit_tumorY)
plt.figtext(0.5, .35, "R-squared: %.4f" % rSqTumor, fontweight='bold')
plt.figtext(0.5, .3, "k_shift: %.4f" % ans[2], fontweight='bold')
plt.figtext(0.5, .25, "k_in: %.4f" % ans[0], fontweight='bold')
plt.figtext(0.5, .2, "k_out: %.4f" % ans[1], fontweight='bold')
```

Please help!!

Comment: I don't know if this is the source of the problem you are having, but the line `k_shift = int(k_shift)` is definitely a problem.  `curve_fit` assumes that the function varies smoothly with the parameters.  If you truncate the parameter to an integer, you are violating an assumption made by `curve_fit`.

Comment: You could try the solution I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50324275/803359)

Comment: Just realized that you are talking about a list index, so to make it continuous in the Jacobian you have to introduce a partial shift via interpolation

Comment: @mikuszefski can you speak more to partial shift via interpolation? Earlier in the code I have a line that does interpolate the data. How do I incorporate K_shift? Also assuming I should move the interpolation into the objective function? 

# interpolate the tumor data for more accurate fitting
timeTumor = np.arange(min(tumor_x), max(tumor_x), 1)
tumorVec = interp1d(tumor_x, tumor_y, fill_value="extrapolate")(timeTumor)

Comment: Ok...so looking even more into it, I see that you eventually integrate a linear interpolation. I guess `k_shift` is somewhat your lower integration boundary. Instead you could split these two, by first making a linear interpolation function like `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` and then use `scipy.integrate.quad` to integrate. here you can have a continuous lower boundary.